# What is the best way to give a directive an inner HTML template?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I'm thinkg about a way to give my tooltip directive an HTML template. The directive use a component as its outer template, but there some time the **inner HTML** of the directive is something the user whould like to design, for example insret an icon orimage inside the tooltip.

This is how the directive works now. You can give it a simple string, an object or designed string:

```
<div [my-tooltip]="'some text...'"></div>
<div [my-tooltip]="objectText"></div>
<div [my-tooltip]="'<div style=\'color:red;\'>text with style</div>'"></div>
```

But this is the simple ways, if user want the tooltip to have more reach HTML rendered like:

```
 <div ng-class="{'icon-success' : mystatus.Status==='SUCCESS'}" style="cursor: pointer">{{myObject.text}}</div>
```

How to do it? 
Where it should go? 
What should I use?
Inner html child? I don't like that approch because there can be inner child that are not part of the tooltip. Please advise.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the ng-bootstrap library to add custom html templates to popovers:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover.